# Erro em código PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Meu código faz parte de um projeto de loja virtual, e está dando o seguinte erro:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue abaixo o código:

```
<?php class Login extends BD{

    private $prefixo = 'ibicor_';
    private $tabela = 'loja_clientes';
    private $email;
    private $senha;

    public function setEmail($mail){
        $this->email = $mail;
    }

    private function getEmail(){
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function setSenha($pass){
        $this->senha = $pass;
    }

    private function getSenha(){
        return $this->senha;
    }

    private function validar(){
        $strSQL = "SELECT * FROM '".$this->tabela."' WHERE email_log = ? AND senha_log = ?";
        $stmt = self::conn()->prepare($strSQL);
        $stmt->execute(array($this->getEmail(), $this->getSenha()));
        return ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) ? true : false;
    }

    public function logar(){
        if($this->validar()){
            $atualizar = self::conn()->prepare("UPDATE '".$this->tabela."' SET data_log = NOW() WHRE email_log = ? AND senha_log = ?");
            $atualizar->execute(array($this->getEmail(), $this->getSenha()));

            $_SESSION[$this->prefixo.'emailLog'] = $this->getEmail();
            $_SESSION[$this->prefixo.'senhaLog'] = $this->getSenha();
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;   
        }
    }

    public function isLogado(){
        if(isset($_SESSION[$this->prefixo.'emailLog'], $_SESSION[$this->prefixo.'senhaLog'])){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function deslogar(){
        if($this->isLogado()){
            unset($_SESSION[$this->prefixo.'emailLog']);
            unset($_SESSION[$this->prefixo.'senhaLog']);
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: E tenha cuidado com os prints que tem informações pessoais. O seu email é visível na imagem de erro, por pouco a sua senha também la aparecia.

Comment: é tudo email de teste

Comment: Coloque o erro como texto, e não imagem, pois dificulta a visualização.

Answer (score 3):

É Erro de sintaxe nomes de tabelas ou campos não devem estar entre aspas simples. Isso vale tanto para o select quando o update do código.

```
"SELECT * FROM '".$this->tabela."'
               ^                 ^
               |  causa do erro  |
```

Comment: já retirei as aspas simples, mas o erro permanece

Answer (score 1):

Na hora que for passar o nome da tabela passa somente o nome dela, sem envolver com aspas simples..

```
"SELECT * FROM ".$this->tabela." WHERE email_log = ? AND senha_log = ?";
```

E aqui também.

```
"UPDATE ".$this->tabela." SET data_log = NOW() WHRE email_log = ? AND senha_log = ?"
```

Comment: já retirei as aspas simples, mas o erro permanece